# open tcp/ip conenctions count is around 2.1 million!

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, connection, tcpip

There are around 1500-2000 users online on this win2008 r2 server on around 50 sites. performance monitor reports around 2.1 million active ip4 conenctions. server is ip6 enabled and has public ip6. although ip6 never used it reports 500-600 active connections on ip6.

are these figures normal?

Comment: Can you paste a screenshot of the perfmon graph, with the statistics from the bottom?

Comment: Sounds very dubious. What do your logs show for the number of hits / average response times?

Comment: Is the source the same for most connections?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those numbers are cumulative, meaning those are the number of active connections that have been established since the server has been running.

You want to look at Connections Established, not Connections Active.